# How to change name of Android Studio Project after creation?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.3

I have created an android studio project names "My AppName".
All the packages are in the namespace `com.mycompanyname.myappname`.

I have decided to change the app name to "My newAppName"

Is there a way to easily refactor this so all changes are made in all files, or do I need to create my project again from scratch?

Comment: do you want to change package name or application name

Comment: @Avinash both....

Answer (score 2):

Open your AndroidManifest.xml file and you should be able to see "My AppName" there. Right-click on it, then select `Refactor -> Rename`.

Comment: Are you referring to android:label ? Is that enough ? What about refactoring the package name...

Comment: If you want to rename only the app name, yes this is enough. If you want to rename the application package, repeat the steps for the "package" field of the <manifest> tag in the beginning of AndroidManifest.xml